# Facebook "Like" and "Comment" integration doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, facebook

The "like" button and the "comment" button works same for all of my posts. How to make it to work individual for every single post. When i comment on one of the posts to not put the comment in all other.  Same with the "Like" button.

I'm sure u know the code. It's from FB, so i wont post the javascript.

"Like":

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://X-X-X.com/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-share="true"></div>
```

"Comment":

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://X-x-x.com/" data-numposts="20" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

I know i have to change something in the data-href but what ? I'm using the main URL...

Comment: You have to use the specific URL for the post, not for your home page.

Comment: yes but i cant for every new article to change the code... should i use php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using php with something like:

```
href="http://X-x-x.com/<?php echo($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>">Link</a>
```

Also, check out: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php